# NSURLConnection Leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Today i faced a little problem, i wanted to know the reason of leak. Here is the code

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

This works fine no problem.

Now i was just wondering what happens to this allocated memory/object since no one is releasing it. So according to instinct i put autorelease while allocating like this:

```
[[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
```

This threw me an error and crash "[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection _withConnectionDisconnectFromConnection]: message sent to deallocated instance"

Just wanted to know the concept and reason behind.

EDIT: I am not using ARC.

Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a related discussion over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345663/nsurlconnection-leak?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection _withConnectionDisconnectFromConnection]

this was called after the Autorelease Pool released your NSURLConnection connection object. 
Best way should be, have a reference for the variable and release it, once you are done fetching the data. (May be in the viewDidUnload: ?)

Comment: Hi, i had already implemented ur solution and yeah it works. I just wanted to know what was going in background, like you pointed out autorelease pool released my object before. So how would i know that autorlease might get called or release my objects before it could be used elsewhere. I am bit confused with this situation concept. Thanks

Comment: See, basically an object is a memory location on heap. And the variables pointing to it are like the owners of it. Imagine a dog as the memory and you are one variable who are holding that dog with one belt. Now if I am another variable pointing to same memory location, imagine I am also holding the dog with my own belt.

Comment: Now when you release me, means I am removing the belt from the dog. But still you are holding it, when you will also release the memory or dog, the dog will run away. When, we might not be able to tell precisely. Same way autorelease pool works, it looks out for these kinda dogs i.e. memory locations and release them eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not use autorelease here for better memory management please release connection object in connection delegate method

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
 {
     [connection release];
 }
```

So when your connection get finished It will release the connection object or you can release it ni viewDidUnload also

Comment: so does this means the memory i allcoated for connection is same as this connection object in "connectionDidFinishLoading". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for better memory management
    **NSURLConnection *connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];**

Above connectionWithRequest method is class method and manage memory itself you don't need to release it.
As far as I know after allocating the connection object objc runtime adds the object to autoreleasepool then other delegate method sent to deallocated instances.